# In Swift, how to write a function that triggers another function once it's complete?

Tags: ios, swift, function, closures

I currently have a function that returns JSON data, in that JSON data is an access token (function uses both AlamoFire & SwiftyJSON):

```
func getAccessToken (username: String, password: String) {

    //code//

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(baseURL)/oauth2/token", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)

        .responseJSON { response in
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {

                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)

                self.accessToken = swiftyJsonVar["access_token"].stringValue

            }
    }
}
```

As soon as I get the access token I want another function to be triggered using the access token that was just gotten:

```
func createNewMember (username: String, password: String, accessToken: String) {
    //code//
}
```

I was thinking of having a closure on the `getAccessToken` function that returns the access token and triggers the `createNewMember` function but am not entirely sure how to set it up. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you make your code more general? And is the first snipper a method? If so you might want to include a class for context.

Comment: You can use a closure if you want to tightly couple the two pieces of code or NSNotification for a loose coupling.

Comment: Why not just implement `createNewMember` as a regular method and call it from within the `.responseJSON` closure that you already have?

Comment: @KyleParent I only have to call the "createNewMember" function once but I have to call the "getAccessToken" function whenever the user logs out and logs back in again

Comment: @J'' The first snippet is a method, once it's complete it should return an access token.  I'm trying to find a way to automatically trigger another method using that access token that was just got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a `completionHandler` pattern, a closure that you will call when the `getAccessToken` call is done, which can return either the token or the error:

```
func getAccessToken (username: String, password: String, completionHandler: (String?, ErrorType?) -> ()) {

    //code//

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(baseURL)/oauth2/token", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard let value = response.result.value else {
                completionHandler(nil, response.result.error)
                return
            }

            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(value)
            completionHandler(swiftyJsonVar["access_token"].string, nil)
    }
}
```

You'd then call it using the completion handler closure:

```
getAccessToken(username, password: password) { token, error in
    guard let accessToken = token where error == nil else {
        // handle error here

        print(error)
        return
    }

    self.createNewMember(username, password: password, accessToken: accessToken)
}
```

Comment: The createNewMember function is only called once.  What would be passed in the completionHandler when it doesn't have to return anything?

Comment: What do you mean "when it doesn't have to return anything"? When you want to get a token and the call `createNewMember`, you do the above. When you want to get a token and do something else with that token, you replace that closure that calls `createNewMember` with some code that does something else. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score -1):

This covers the setup - createNewMember is a closure passed in as an argument to `getAccessToken`, and is implemented by the caller. This way the caller will receive and decide what to do with the access token once it's retrieved.

```
// Added createNewMember as a parameter
func getAccessToken (username: String, password: String, createNewMember:(username: String, password: String, accessToken: String)) {

    //code//

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(baseURL)/oauth2/token", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)

        .responseJSON { response in
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {

                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)

                self.accessToken = swiftyJsonVar["access_token"].stringValue
                // Call the closure after retrieving the access token
                createNewMember(username, password, self.accessToken)
            }
    }
}
```